# Resizing image using capinsets

Tags: ios, ios5, uibutton, uiimage, image-resizing

I have setup a button like this:

```
// Create facebook login button
facebookLoginButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300,50)];
facebookLoginButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
//NSLog(@"facebook button view height is %f",facebookLoginButton.bounds.size.height);
//NSLog(@"facebook button view width is %f",facebookLoginButton.bounds.size.width);

UIImage *facebookButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookLogin"]
                           resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16,140,86,92)];
[facebookLoginButton setBackgroundImage:facebookButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have created an image in Photoshop for the button which is 200(w)x100(h)px. Firstly would this be the correct size for the retina image used on an iphone4/5 for a button fitting into the login frame which is 50 in height? The other width does not matter as being stretched.

Secondly, below is an example image. I cannot seem to work out the correct insets for the 'resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake'. How do I work this out? Is there a tutorial anywhere on how to do this, other than the Android example I have seen linked from SO.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are setting the frame of the button explicitly, and since you are creating your own image, you do not need a resizable image. Your button is 300 by 50 so make a 300 by 50 image (along with a 600 by 100 image for a double-resolution device) and set the background image of the button to it.

However, I'll also give a code example. For the image that you actually give, if you name it FacebookLogin@2x.png so that it is used as the double-resolution image, the value you want to use is `resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,50,0,50)`. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: The example image is 200x100 pixels and needs to be stretched so the the F stays on the left and the right part stretched

Comment: Okay, I've edited the answer to play along with the image you actually give.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted as answer - I have actually created another issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713799/image-not-resizing-correctly-using-resizableimagewithcapinsets - this is practically the same answer. But if you can provide information on  how this is worked out or any useful tutorials to learn from that would be great. I couldn't find anything in the Apple docs that was useful/in depth.

Comment: Well, the image is 100 tall but the button is 50 tall. So this must be a double resolution image. So you have to name it @2x. But for the actual image you have to think in normal points. So the *image* is 50 tall - and 100 wide. You want it to stretch horizontally in the middle, so the insets are 50 from the left and 50 from the right; thus the single column of pixels in the middle are repeated as needed to fill out the middle of the resulting image in the button. More in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_uiimage_and_uiimageview

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script to generate the resizable image with cap insets. Very useful.  https://github.com/kejinlu/capimage