# Progress view not rounded on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have set some images to custom a UIProgressView and give a rounded style to it, but the problem is when the progress value is changed the control is not anymore rounded on iOS 7.

**Here is the code that i use:**

```
self.progressBar.progressImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prog_progress"];
self.progressBar.trackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prog_track"];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 5.0f);
self.progressBar.transform = transform;
```

**Progress View Changes:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried providing a scalable image?

Comment: Did you set clipsToBounds to YES ?

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Yes, i have set clipsToBounds but nothing changed.

Comment: @AdilSoomro What do you mean a scalable image?

Comment: @User123456 Have a look here: [Resizing image using capinsets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15703301/593709)

Answer (score 0):

Please add category to UIProgressView as below

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
            return CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The progressbar has roundet corners. Have a closer look. Due your skaling you are compressing the image along with its corners. Even if setting insets this aproach will never work. Smal numbers will at one point drop below the inset.

There are many aproaches, but given your image aproach:
A simple blue view under an imageview. the image view has your white image with the grey bar. Give the grey area trabsparency, so the blue is visible. Now u can set the blue view to any size without loosing the round corners.